# uwp How to read the files under the specified directory

Tags: c#, file, uwp

(c# UWP) How to read files in any directory without using file selectors?
This is my code：

```
var t = Task.Run(() => File.ReadAllText(@"D:\chai.log"));
```

t.Wait();

Thrown exception：

```
Access to the path 'D:\chai.log' is denied.
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Access to user's files and folders are denied. In a UWP app, only the files or folders that are picked by the user can be accessed to read or write.

To show a dialog for the user to pick files or folders, write this code below:

```
var picker = new Windows.Storage.Pickers.FileOpenPicker();
picker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".log");

Windows.Storage.StorageFile file = await picker.PickSingleFileAsync();
if (file != null)
{
    // Application now has read/write access to the picked file
}
```

Read [Open files and folders with a picker - UWP app developer | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/quickstart-using-file-and-folder-pickers) for more details of the `FileOpenPicker`.

---

If you want future access to the files or folders the user picked this time, use `MostRecentlyUsedList` to track these files and folders.

```
Windows.Storage.StorageFile file = await picker.PickSingleFileAsync();

var mru = Windows.Storage.AccessCache.StorageApplicationPermissions.MostRecentlyUsedList;
string mruToken = mru.Add(file, "Some log file");
```

And you can enumerate your `mru` later to access the files or folders in the future:

```
foreach (Windows.Storage.AccessCache.AccessListEntry entry in mru.Entries)
{
    string mruToken = entry.Token;
    string mruMetadata = entry.Metadata;
    Windows.Storage.IStorageItem item = await mru.GetItemAsync(mruToken);
    // The type of item will tell you whether it's a file or a folder.
}
```

Read [Track recently used files and folders - UWP app developer | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/how-to-track-recently-used-files-and-folders) for more details of the `MostRecentlyUsedList`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply, but we asked uwp to read files without feeling, so the way of FileOpenPicker has been ruled out. In addition, MostRecentlyUsedList is also not good, because our requirement is to read only the files under the specified directory, and the files in other directories are not read.

Comment: This is the only available method to achieve your goal. UWP doesn't allow applications to access files or folders without asking the user for permissions. You can ask the user to select the folder on the first run and use the `MostRecentlyUsedList` to store the folder so that there is no need to ask the user again.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Let's reconsider this.

Answer (score 2):

Windows 10 Build 17093 introduced `broadFileSystemAccess` capability which allows apps to access folders which the current user has access to.

> This is a restricted capability. On first use, the system will prompt
>   the user to allow access. Access is configurable in Settings > Privacy
>
> > File system. If you submit an app to the Store that declares this capability, you will need to supply additional descriptions of why
> >     your app needs this capability, and how it intends to use it. This
> >     capability works for APIs in the Windows.Storage namespace

---

**MSDN Documentation**

[broadFileSystemAccess](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/file-access-permissions#accessing-additional-locations)

[Windows.Storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.Storage)

Comment: Thanks! It seems that it's a new API for us to access users folders. My app targets the newest Windows so I can have a try.